# Vue add content inside #document-fragment

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I'm using vue3 with nuxt3 and want to add a template tag with content inside the generated `#document-fragment`. The resulting HTML should look like this:

```
<body>
  <template id="some-id">
    #document-fragment
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
  </template>
</body>
```

when I use plain html, that works great. With vue3 the elements are not inside the `#document-fragment` but below it like this:

```
<body>
  <template id="some-id">
    #document-fragment
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  </template>
</body>
```

My vue3 code looks like this (similar to the html code):

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <template id="some-id">
      <div></div>
    </template>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

is there any way to put the content inside the `#document-fragment` element?

Comment: I don't see a difference between the first two snippets. Is it me?

Comment: in the first snippet, the `<div>` is INSIDE the `#document-fragment`, in the second snippet it is BELOW. I need it to be inside, but I can't achieve that with vue so far.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using a ref on the template tag and then the `render`-function.

```
<template id="some-id" ref="someRef">
</template>
```

```
const someRef: Ref<HTMLTemplateElement | undefined> = ref()
onMounted(() => {
  if (someRef.value?.content) {
    // @ts-ignore
    render('div', someRef.value.content)
  }
})
```

if you want to insert a component you can use the it like this:

```
const someRef: Ref<HTMLTemplateElement | undefined> = ref()
onMounted(() => {
  if (someRef.value?.content) {
    // @ts-ignore
    render(h(SomeComponent, { someProp: someValue }), someRef.value.content)
  }
})
```

Maybe there is a better, but for now that works.